# Can't install Cupy with pip and Cuda

Tags: pip, cupy

i'm having issues on installing cupy with the command: pip install cupy-cuda102

System details:
OS: Windows 10 Home
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 820M
Python version: 3.6.4
Pip version: 21.3.1
Cuda version: 10.2.89

Error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupy-cuda102 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cupy-cuda102

Also pip install cupy doesn't work.

I'm stuck at this point, does anyone have idea of why I can't install Cupy?

Comment: Not directly related to the installation issue, but GeForce 820M is not supported by CuPy. NVIDIA CUDA GPU with the Compute Capability 3.0 or larger` is required (https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cupy has

```
python_requires='>=3.7',
```

in the setup.py file. Also [cuyp-cuda102](https://pypi.org/project/cupy-cuda102/#files) only has whl files starting at python 3.7. This is why no installation candidate can be found.

As noted in the comments however, your GPU is not compatible with CUPY